# oData v4 (6.1.0) nested $filter in $expand

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an asp.net 4.5 Web Api oData v4 service that is working really well but I have  encountered a problem today with nested $filters in $expand.

It says [here](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/)

> that OData V4 supports nested filters in $expand. The request below
>   return People and all their trips with Name "Trip in US".
>
> GET serviceRoot/People?$expand=Trips($filter=Name eq 'Trip in US')

and it shows a nice example of data that does just that.

There is also a coded example in the [Web API for oData v4 Docs here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-03-filter-in-expand)

I have an HTTP call like this:

```
serviceRoot/Languages?$expand=translations
```

which returns a list of Languages with their expanded translations and I can filter that top-level list down with this:

```
serviceRoot/Languages?$expand=translations&$filter=isoLanguageShortName eq 'en'
```

However, I can't filter the expanded translations with this:

```
serviceRoot/Languages?$expand=translations($filter=languageName eq 'English')
```

That call seems to be the same as the one in the quote above and the effect should be same on my data as theirs.

Does anyone know where am I going wrong? Do I need to set something in my ASP.NET code for this to work (like we need to add MaxExpansionDepth to EnableQueryAttribute for querying deeper than two levels)?

Comment: Can't it just be a version problem ? this support has been added with v5.5. I tested the [sample](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-03-filter-in-expand) with [v5.5.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.5.1) and it is actually working. Which version are you using (6.1.0 doesn't exist yet) ?

Comment: Many thanks @Fabian.  I have three libraries with the oData icon that report version 6.1.0 and then the library that you linked to that, I can now see, reports 5.4.0, I guess this is the main library!  Your comment has just made a good start to what is going to be a very long day.  Thanks again. :-)

Comment: Is it working ? Can I add an answer to close the topic ?

Comment: please do, and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a versioning problem. The support for has been added with version 5.5. I tested the [sample](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-03-filter-in-expand) with [v5.5.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.5.1) and it is actually working.

As @lukkea confirmed he was using 5.4.0.

(Version 6.1.0 indicated in the title corresponds to [odata core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/) libraries which is a dependency of odata web api library Microsoft.AspNet.OData)